# Calling a service on a custom class returns Catchable Fatal Error in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I've created a new service in symfony2 with "security.context" as arguments.
But when I call the service on a custom class or a class that is not a controller, it always return a missing argument error. May I know whats wrong with this code?

Here is my service.

```
appbundle.common.services.loggeduserservice:
    class: Makubex\Pim\AppBundle\Common\Services\LoggedUserService
    arguments: ["@security.context"]
```

Here is my service class.

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;
class LoggedUserService{
private $context;

public function __construct(AppContext $context)
{
    $this->context = $context;
}

public function getCurrentUser()
{
    return $this->context;
}
}
```

My custom class.

```
class makubex{

public function getUser(){
  $user = new LoggedUserService();
  echo $user->getId();
  }
}
```

Comment: I forgot, here is the exact error message. Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Makubex\Pim\AppBundle\Common\Services\LoggedUserService::__construct() must be an instance of Makubex\InfrastructureBundle\Application\AppContext, none given, called in C:\wamp\www\pim\src\Makubex\Pim\AppBundle\Backoffice\CommandProcessors\SaveCustomAttributeCommandProcessor.php on line 28 and defined in C:\wamp\www\pim\src\Makubex\Pim\AppBundle\Common\Services\LoggedUserService.php line 19 (500 Internal Server Error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few things wrong here:

1. If you're using Symfony 2.6 or newer you should not use `security.context`, it is [deprecated](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-security-component-improvements)
2. `AppContext` is not valid type hint for your what you're injecting. You probably want to inject `security.token_storage` service and then your type hint would be `TokenStorageInterface`
3. If you want to use Symfony's service container then you don't instantiate classes by calling `new` keyword (e.g. `new LoggedUserService()`). Instead you should call `get` method on `ContainerInterface` instance (e.g. `$user = $this->container->get('appbundle.common.services.loggeduserservice')`). To do that you need to have access to container in your custom class (`makubex`) so you will have to inject it as well.

So, after all your code should look something like:

**services.yml**

```
appbundle.common.services.loggeduserservice:
    class: Makubex\Pim\AppBundle\Common\Services\LoggedUserService
    arguments: ["@security.token_storage"]
```

Service class:

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface

class LoggedUserService{

    private $context;

    public function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $context)
    {
        $this->context = $context;
    }

    public function getCurrentUser()
    {
        return $this->context;
    }
}
```

Your class:

```
class makubex{

    public function __construct($container) {
        $this->container = $container;
        //you need to inject container or just inject only instance of your LoggedUserService not whole container since this is considered as a bad practice
    }

    public function getUser(){
        $user = $this->container->get('appbundle.common.services.loggeduserservice');
        echo $user->getId();
    }
}
```